# Golang test for go-routine with channel

Tags: go, goroutine

I’ve the following function which prints dots to the terminal while executing 
Some process, the code is **working as expected** but now I want to test it.
How should I do that

```
func printdot(finish <-chan struct{}) {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer t.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            fmt.Print(".")
        case <-finish:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test

```
func Test_printdot(t *testing.T) {

    finish := make(chan struct{})
    start := time.Now()
    go printdot(finish)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    sec := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    switch int(sec) {
    case 0:
        // Output:
    case 1:
        // Output: .
    case 2:
        // Output: ..
    case 3:
        // Output: ...
    default:
        t.Error(“Too much time…”)
    }

     close(finish)
}
```

Now the test is continue running without stop even that Im using the finish code , any idea how to improve it ?

Comment: don't understand u. just run your code and it's okay:  go test -v
=== RUN   Test_printdot
.--- PASS: Test_printdot (1.00s)
PASS
ok    1.002s

Answer (score 2):

Closing a channel doesn't send data, so code will never reach the `return` in the goroutine. This trick working with range operator. You can do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

func printdot(finish <-chan struct{}, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer t.Stop()
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            fmt.Print(".")
        case <-finish:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I added sync.WaitGroup for "waiting" while goroutine will end

```
package main


import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "sync"
        "testing"

    )

func Test_printdot(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    finish := make(chan struct{})
    start := time.Now()
    go printdot(finish, wg)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    sec := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    switch int(sec) {
    case 0:
        // Output:
    case 1:
        // Output: .
    case 2:
        // Output: ..
    case 3:
        // Output: ...
    default:
        t.Error("Too much time…")
    }

    finish <- struct{}{}
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tryied it and still the test doesnt ends up..., any idea why ?